# Не подскажите, а есть ли готовый репликатор данных из firebird в mongodb, как например для mysql tungsten replicator

Tags: mongodb, firebird, репликация

Можно ли организовать такое взаимодействие с помощью репликации master slave, например

Comment: Что вы понимаете под синхронизацией? Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Здравствуйте, имею ввиду репликацию, возможно конечно не в полной мере. Чтобы при внесении изменений в firebird они отображались в такой же бд, но в MongoDB

Comment: [Поправте вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/767618/edit).

Comment: Я попробовал с помощью  репликации ошибок не выдает, но работает не корректно, не все изменения передаются

Comment: А какие то изменения передаются ? Это разные базы данных.  Более того, одна из них реляционная, а другая нет.  То есть, у них даже сущности, которые вы хотите реплицировать разные (например, таблица / коллекция). Не думаю, что это можно сделать с помощью существующих инструментов. Скорее всего, надо будет писать свой код.

Comment: Да, это понимаю, что придется скрипт писать, не знаю как лучше организовать запуск скрипта и преобразование данных. Поскольку оно нужно не всегда, а только при внесении изменений в MongoDB

Comment: Не подскажите, а есть ли готовый репликатор, как например для mysql tungsten replicator